# IHttpModule inserting an inbound Filter break WCF, how to tweak Content-Length?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, httpmodule, httprequest

In ASP.NET 4.0, I have an `IHttpModule` that apply a filter on `HttpRequest.Filter`. As the result, the content stream length is changed, and it breaks WCF with now returns `400 bad request` because of the mismatch between the body length and the HTTP headers.

Any idea how to solve this behavior of WCF?

Answer (score 2):

All that is really needed is to delete the erroneous Content-Length header, but that isn't allowed in IIS6.  Not sure about IIS7 in integrated pipeline mode.  For any response that uses your filter, apply this update to the headers.  The idea is to get the content type (so you don't break any non-text responses) and any cookies present (so you don't break authentication), clear all the headers (to clear the Content-Length), then set the content type and cookies again.  We apply our filter in the HttpApplication.ReleaseRequestState event and then do the following processing. YMMV.

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
string ct = app.Response.ContentType;
HttpCookie[] cookies = new HttpCookie[app.Response.Cookies.Count];
app.Response.Cookies.CopyTo(cookies, 0);

app.Response.ClearHeaders();

app.Response.ContentType = ct;
foreach (HttpCookie cookie in cookies) { app.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is for your question:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/fa132e84-3e3f-4152-9ffa-3f860a266e9f/

Comment: Yes, same problem. Unfortunately, the discussion only acknowledge the problem, without providing a solution for it.